# JSF 2.0 + PrimeFaces: dataTable page-numeration does not work

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, datatable, primefaces

I am using Mojarra 2.0.3 on Tomcat 6.0 and PrimeFaces 2.2.1.

I use a dataTable with lazyloading, which works without problems. Now i added pagination and the table calculates the number of pages not correctly.

```
<p:dataTable id="tableList" value="#{overview.lazyModel}" rendered="#{!overview.listEmpty}" var="e"
    paginator="true" rows="10" lazy="true"
    paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="5, 10, 20, 50">
```

On first load, sometimes it displays no data, though the bean sent it correctly (I print the data, sent to the table, into the Tomcat-console) and also the data from the table (pagesize, filters, sortMode, ...) is correct.

```
lazyModel = new LazyDataModel<Bericht>() {
    @Override  
    public List<Bericht> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, boolean sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters) {
        List<Bericht> lazyBerichte;     

        lazyBerichte = [...]; // fill data
        setRowCount([...]); // set row count

        return lazyBerichte;
    };          
}
```

I hope that it's not a bug in primefaces, because i can't wait until the new version is out (project must be ready in 3 weeks).

Does anyone have an idea? I tried everything out but nothing's working.

Greets from germany, Andy

Answer (score 1):

well, I suppose you are getting an arithmetic exception division by 0, try adding rowCount and pageSize after instanciate your lazy datamodel object. something like

```
lazyModel = new LazyDataModel<Bericht>() {
    @Override  
    public List<Bericht> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, boolean sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters) {
        List<Bericht> lazyBerichte;     

        lazyBerichte = [...]; // fill data
        setRowCount([...]); // set row count

        return lazyBerichte;
    };   
   lazyModel.setRowCount(totalRowsNumberWithoutFilters); //you should put here the total rows of your table, something like a select * from x or findAll() jpa method
   lazyModel.setPageSize(10); //put the rows per page number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You used below attribute for pagination

```
paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
```

You kept all things for paginatorTemplate But you forgot to add one more

```
{PageLinks}
```

add this one also it will work.